# Do delivery attempts in GCP pubsub get reset after some time?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have enabled a Dead Lettering and set the maximum delivery attempts for my pull subscription. I have tested that the delivery attempt increases as its supposed to if I do not acknowledge the pulled message.

However if I do not pull the message for some time (seems to be around 10 min), the delivery attempt seems to go back to 1, or get reset...

Is this the expected behavior or is this only happening to me?

In the docs there is nothing regarding a reset after a specific period of time: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/handling-failures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delivery attempts are set on a best-effort basis and are not persisted so it is possible that if a message is not retrieved for awhile, it will be reset to zero, yes.

Comment: Is there some timing for the reset, or is it random? Could it be reset after 1 min  for example? Or is it guaranteed to not reset for at least 10 min?

Comment: There are no guarantees on when the delivery count will reset. It could happen at any point.

Comment: I am wondering what is the point of the dead lettering then... If you set a high max delivery attempt of 100 for example, it might never be reached and never be forwarded to the dead letter.

Comment: The idea is that you may have a message that is continually being delivered and crashing your subscribers because it is an unexpected message. In the presence of rapid repeat deliveries, you ultimately want it to go to a dead-letter topic so it stops causing crashes. If your subscriber is in a continual state of pulling, this happens relatively quickly. But if you are pulling only once every ten minutes, then there is somewhat less risk to your jobs. Also, pulling once every ten minutes is a bit of an anti-pattern for Cloud Pub/Sub. Usually, you want subscribers to be pulling continuously.

Comment: I understand, thanks for explaining!

Comment: btw is it possible to request an update to the docs to mention this point? It could be very helpful for others too.

Comment: Yes, I already put an internal request in to clarify the docs.